# GL_INVALID_OPERATION when not even using OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es, textview

I am creating a simple scoreboard application, and I am getting a GL_INVALID_OPERATION in LogCat.  I don't use OpenGL in this app at all, and it's not in the Manifest or anything.  It also only happens when I do specific things.  For example, I represent each side's score with a `TextView`.  When a `TextView` is tapped, it increments the number by 1.  When I increment either TextView to 20, for some reason the number disappears.  Then, if I tap again, it comes back and says 21.  Also, when the number disappears, the following shows up in LogCat:

```
12-20 20:15:23.128  12744-12744/com.vcapra1.pingpongscoreboard W/Adreno-ES20﹕ <gl_draw_error_checks:575>: GL_INVALID_OPERATION
12-20 20:15:23.128  12744-12744/com.vcapra1.pingpongscoreboard D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x502
12-20 20:15:23.128  12744-12744/com.vcapra1.pingpongscoreboard E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ GL_INVALID_OPERATION
```

Nowhere in my code does the number 20 appear in referencing to the value of a TextView.

ALSO - I thought I would add that it only happens when the other score is 0 or 1.

Could anybody tell me why the number disappears and causes this error?

This is shown here:

[image: Scoreboard Bug]

Comment: Hello Vinnie, did you get it to work? Facing same issue but for me it happens when the screen is locked (automatically or by pressing the power button).